Need to extend embed functionality in the buzzy script laravel
To extend the tweet embed functionality to accept URLs with the x.com domain in addition to those with the twitter.com domain, i want to implement the following change:
"Modify the tweet embed function to accept URLs from both the twitter.com and x.com domains.
can't able to find the file where this stuff manage.
Is anyone worked on that modification? Please i need a help
Here i am enter link of x.com but its allow only twitter.com
